# Intellij can't import static org.junit.Assert.assertthat

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, assert

I need to use the method `org.junit.Assert.assertEquals`in my test script but the `Assert` remains red and shows as an unresolved symbol. I do installed the `junit` and I don't know why only the `Assert` remains unresolved. I'm new to java btw. Here is [the screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Raovo.png)

Really need some help! Thank you so much!

PS: I saw there was another post about this issue and resolved by `import static org.junit.Assert.*;` but this doesn't work at my side.

Comment: Add JUnit dependency to your build file?

Comment: `org.junit.Assert.assertEquals` is used in JUnit4, you need to check whether you are using junit 4 or junit 5.

Comment: @Haoliang It seems like I used junit 5. How should I inmportwith Junit 5 then? thank you!

Comment: Don't post images of code, just post the code itself.

Comment: You also seem to be mixing two test frameworks. Are you supposed to use JUnit or TestNG?

Answer (score 1):

In [JUnit 5](https://junit.org/junit5/), you can import [assertion methods](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-assertions) like follows:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class UnitTest {

    // we can use JUnit 5's @Test annotation
    @Test
    void testEquals() {
        assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

In [JUnit 4](https://junit.org/junit4/), [assertions](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Assertions) use the imports as you are using: `import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;`

Answer (score -1):

Add spring boot starter test maven dependency and then do static import.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
```

Comment: You don't need Spring to use JUnit.